# vertical toggle for asp submenu items

Tags: javascript, c#, bootstrap-4, asp.net-4.0, aspmenu-control

I'm working on asp menu with vertical orientation and trying to toggle the submenu items in  same list.

I want to achieve something like this.

[image]

and right now i've submenu in extended list like this.

[image]

Following is my code.

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="1"  
    RenderingMode="List" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"  CssClass="menu-item-parent"                              
    OnMenuItemDataBound="NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound"
    OnDataBound="NavigationMenu_DataBound">
</asp:Menu>
```

I am not sure how can i display the submenu in same list. can please someone suggest a solution?
Thanks in advance.